# Dynamically resize drop down width when bolded

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple drop down list such as this:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="MyVeryFirstLongValue">MyFirstLongestValue</option>
    <option value="MyVerySecondLongValue">MySecondLongValue</option>
</select>
```

When I run this on its own the width of the dropdown is exactly as it needs to be.  It auto adjusts.  However, my problem now is when I make the text bold.

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="MyVeryFirstLongValue">MyFirstLongestValue</option>
    <option value="MyVerySecondLongValue">MySecondLongValue</option>
</select>

select{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now the text gets cut off.  How can I maintain the auto width based on the text and still have it bolded?  The text in the drop down is dynamic so I cannot give it a fixed width.

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z3enm7L8/)

[image: What I see on JS Fiddle]

Comment: Looks fine here on MacOS FF, Chrome and Safari... although I only see bolding on FF.

Comment: no problem on  Windows Chrome, mozilla firefox.. no text gets cut off. But on firebox both option are bold. in chrome only selected option is bold. If I add extra text on any option the width set on that option text [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/ea0wjon6/ ]

Comment: it is interesting that we are all getting different results, I'll upload some pictures to show what I see

Comment: what browser is that?

Comment: That is Chrome Browser

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce it only in chrome

It could be an option to have bold options also:

```
select,option{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I cannot have the options bolded.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try adding some padding to the box?

```
input {
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```